# DCS fridge at times very loud

Tags: refrigerator

I have a [DCS RF195](https://appliancist.com/cooling/refrigerators/dcs-36-inch-french-door-refrigerator-rf195adux1.html) fridge.

This fridge always worked fine, and is 8 yrs old.

Lately, it will at times be very loud. So loud, that it interferes with watching TV, for instance.

Once I open the fridge door, the sound goes away. But after the closing the door, the loud hum sound will return after a few seconds.

Is my fridge failing?

What part should I be replacing?

When it is loud, I tried jostling the fridge, tip it a little, but the sound remains.

Comment: Did you move the fridge any before the hum started?  For cleaning or something.  Check level of fridge, front to back, side to side.   If possible clean fan, and check all pieces are mounted tight.  The other possible reason is problem with motor/compressor,  hopefully just bad/loose mounting.

Comment: Sounds like the compressor is working hard. It could be dying. You won't really know until it's dead. Check your freezer for any ice buildup against the back wall. Your defrost cycle might not be running properly so the compressor has to work hard to try and cool an inaccessible fridge compartment.